# How do I correctly apply group by on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
COL:SPM  COL:BS COL:PL2    COL:PL3  sum
   CCTC       BG      OP      OTH    1
   CCTC       BG      tech    OTH    3
   CCTC       BG      OP      OTH    5
   CCTC       BG      Info    OTH    10
```

I am applying groupby as I want my data to be grouped on all these columns spm,bs,pl2,pl3:

Expected Result:

```
COL:SPM  COL:BS COL:PL2    COL:PL3  sum
   CCTC       BG      OP      OTH    6
   CCTC       BG      tech    OTH    3
   CCTC       BG      Info    OTH    10
```

The result I am getting:

```
  COL:SPM  COL:BS COL:PL2    COL:PL3  sum
       CCTC       BG      OP      OTH    some unverified integer value

df.groupby(['SPM','BS','PL2','PL3'])['sum'].sum().reset_index()
```

I am not understanding why I am getting the result wrong?
I have searched on the net and I have been unsuccessful in finding the solution

Comment: It's hard to understand your question as asked.  Can you edit your question to include a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a small bit of code that we can easily copy and run) that reproduces this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this minimal example code. Does it work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SPM': ['CCTC', 'CCTC', 'CCTC', 'CCTC'],
                   'BS': ['BG', 'BG', 'BG', 'BG'],
                   'PL2': ['OP', 'tech', 'OP', 'Info'],
                   'PL3': ['OTH', 'OTH', 'OTH', 'OTH'],
                   'sum': [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10]})

out = df.groupby(['SPM', 'BS', 'PL2', 'PL3']).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    SPM  BS   PL2  PL3  sum
0  CCTC  BG    OP  OTH    1
1  CCTC  BG  tech  OTH    3
2  CCTC  BG    OP  OTH    5
3  CCTC  BG  Info  OTH   10

>>> out
    SPM  BS   PL2  PL3  sum
0  CCTC  BG  Info  OTH   10
1  CCTC  BG    OP  OTH    6
2  CCTC  BG  tech  OTH    3
```